# Python slicing and broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

Would anyone have any ideas to the following ?

I have a nested loop that works as follows:

```
width = image.shape[0] # returns 450
height = image.shape[1] # returns 800

target = np.zeros_like(image) # has shape (450,800,3)
...
for i in range(0,width):
    for j in range(0,height):
        target[i,j] = out_rgb[i,j]
```

where

```
print(np.shape(target)) #returns (450, 800, 3)
print(np.shape(out_rgb)) #returns (450, 800)
print(np.shape(out_rgb[0][0])) #returns (3,) and likewise to np.shape(out_rgb[449][799])
```

I am now trying to avoid the above nested looping and have tried the following:

target[0:width,0:height,:] = out_rgb[0:width,0:height]

which returns

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (450,800) into shape (450,800,3)

np.reshape(out_rgb, (...)) doesn't seem to work for ==> (450,800,3)

Would anyone have any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post erratum in comments

Comment: try `target[:] = out_rgb[...,None]`.  That is, make the rhs (450, 800,1) shaped.  That can broadcast the size 1 dimension to 3,

Answer (score 1):

Because they are totally two different shape
The shape of target is [w,h,d] and out_rgb is [w,h]
You could try

```
target[0:width,0:height] = out_rgb[0:width,0:height]
```

Or
Try change the shape of the variable out_rgb
I hope this could help you